# How to use Adhoc distribution as a team admin?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios-provisioning, provisioning-profile, ad-hoc-distribution

I downloaded the iPhone distribution certificate of my team agent and installed it in the my key chain access after that I created adhoc distribution profile(with certicate of my team agent) and downloaded it to the xcode but I get an error in xcode "No private key/certificate found". I think that this error is because I downloaded the certificate of team agent and I don't have the private key for that. Now is this the solution that I ask my team agent to export his private key for me? Is there any other solution that I can do without asking him for the private key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no other solution then to get your agent's private key. Ask him to do an export as .p12 file of his private key.